# swiftui build error (module map file not found)

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

As same as the title, I saw an error like below.

unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/fasd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/afds-fdasd-iOS-safddsafsdds/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GeneratedModuleMaps/iphonesimulator/SourceKit.modulemap' not found

My SwiftUI project isn't using cocoapods or any other package manager. I only use SPM.

I did Clean Build Folder, Clean cocoapods cache, Reinstall Xcode, Remove all xcode cache.
Please Help me. Thanks.

**Reproduce**

macOS 10.15.3 (19D76)

Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

[1 project]

--> [iOS target (iOS 13.2 iphone and ipad)]

--> [macOS target (macOS 10.15)]

[image]

Comment: It is rarely possible to find solution just by error message. Would you provide some steps, some code, environment (like Xcode version), etc. to reproduce or narrow the area? Then it would be possible to do something.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for advising about questioning! Any other information you want?